# How to set correct expectations and still not lose a job for which I may be underqualified

Tags: salary

I am based in UK and I tried my luck interviewing in the Silicon Valley. After three full days of interviews, I asked the company for the equivalent of a 10% raise in my current salary, and they came back offering to double my salary.

I am honored by such a generous offer, but at the same time I feel that they might be too enthusiastic. They liked me so much that they didn't bother doing a technical interview at all. I consider myself a mid-level developer, and the salary they are offering is closer to what a senior developer would make in UK.
And it's a UK based role, so it's not about scaling for a different region.

They said they want to give me reasons to join AND stay there.

I don't want to lose this opportunity, and I really like my new company. However, I am afraid of betraying their expectations.

How to avoid pissing them off when they find out I am not worth the price they chose to pay?

Comment: "How to avoid losing this chance?" - If you like their offer, and you like the company, take it. I'm not sure what you're worried about by "betraying their expectations." What do you mean by that?

Comment: Remember that salaries are just much higher in Silicon Valley. You'll need it to pay the rent!

Comment: So to summarise you think you have "tricked" the company into believing you are better than you actually are, despite the fact they spent "three full days" interviewing you, and when they find out they might fire you- and you want techniques for preventing that? Are you aware of Imposter Syndrome? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome

Comment: @MarvMills Perfect!   Trust me, the salary is not really mind-numbing. It's according to the living standards in SV, which is very costly!

Comment: But the role is UK based!

Comment: Maybe your perception of salaries is skewed. In London a senior developer salary might be £50-£70K, junior £25-£35K. If the job's in Hull you could probably buy a yacht on that.

Comment: How to avoid losing this chance?  Pretty simple - accept the job offer.

Comment: This is the perfect situation to be in. How would you ever grow professionally if you did not accept jobs that you felt were going to be a challenge for you?

Comment: Brad, I agree that it is important to be challenged, but this salary is either  A) senior developer, which I am not, or B) director level, and I don't have responsibilities over other people.
They were all so happy, and I am really afraid they will soon be resentful...

Comment: In fairness, they made the offer.  If you take the job, and they aren't happy with your qualifications, I see one of two things happening: 1) you get trained and grow into the role 2) you are fired, but now have a big SV firm on your CV, and a higher salary history from which to negotiate.  I don't see how it's a bad move for you to take the job.

Comment: They don't want you to find out in 6 months that your coworkers all make twice what you do for the same job.

Comment: And there is no divinely ordained salary for a given job

Comment: the question is on hold. I don't understand: some users understood it well enough to give me a useful answer, while others felt entitled to put the question on hold. What is the point?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> After three full days of interviews,

The company probably got good enough of a picture of you in those three full days to make the informed decision of hiring you.

> I don't want to lose this opportunity, and I really like my new
>   company. However, I am afraid of betraying their expectations.
>
> How to avoid losing this chance?

Don't be. Do your best, and realise that the company probably knows very well what to expect.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they'd give a job offer if they know (or have the idea) that you won't do well. (Companies have the capacity to do background investigation. Just consider the series of interviews you had too.)

They made their assessment, and I don't think that their capacity to perceive what you can do isn't good. So, isn't this related to self-confidence? (Did you not answer the interview questions honestly?)

Anyway, don't worry too much about what they expect, as long as you answered them honestly during the interviews AND as long as you are willing to learn and to do your best.

PS: Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

This may be a great opportunity but it's unusual enough to put the thinking cap on and do a few checks

1. Three days of interviews seems a lot, even for Silicon Valley. Google typically does 4 hours, Apple 1 day or 2 half days, etc. If they didn't do technical assessments, what did they do? Did you feel they did a good job?
2. Check your salary offer against the "going" rate on salary.com and similar websites. If it's way out of range, that would be unusual
3. Do background checks on the company. Are they a known entity or something in "stealth mode"
4. Keep in mind that cost of living in Silicon Valley is very high and accordingly average salaries are higher than pretty much anywhere else.

Comment: There isn't a website called saaray.com